# Calling a class's constructor inside another class

Tags: c++

I have a test next week for c++ and I'm preparing myself for it. I'm confused when I have 2 classes as shown below. I have to walk through the execution of the code, line by line, and I'm confused about the marked lines (`x = ...` and `y = ...` inside `class two`) - where does execution go from there?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class one {
    int n;
    int m;
    public:
    one() { n = 5; m = 6; cout << "one one made\n"; }
    one(int a, int b) {
        n = a;
        m = b;
        cout << "made one one\n";
    }
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &, one);
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, one a) {
    return os << a.n << '/' << a.m << '=' <<
        (a.n/a.m) << '\n';
}

class two {
    one x;
    one y;
    public:
    two() { cout << "one two made\n"; }
    two(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
        x = one(a, b);  //here is my problem
        y = one(c, d);  //here is my problem
        cout << "made one two\n";
    }
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &, two);
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, two a) {
    return os << a.x << a.y;
}

int main() {
    two t1, t2(4, 2, 8, 3);
    cout << t1 << t2;
    one t3(5, 10), t4;
    cout << t3 << t4;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? What are you trying to do?

Comment: when I get to x = one(a,b); I don't know where to go after that.

Comment: What do you mean "when I get to" and "where to go"? Are you trying to trace the execution of the program, line by line?

Comment: I am doing the work on a piece of paper and I have to walkthrough the program.

Answer (score 3):

```
x = one(a, b);  //here is my problem
y = one(c, d);  //here is my problem
```

What this code does is that it calls the constructor of the class `one` and assigns the newly created instance of this class to the variables `x` and `y`.

The constructor of class `one` is in line 9.

Comment: It depends on what values you give to the constructor of `two`. After executing your main class, you will have (for `t2`) `x=one(4,2)` and `y=one(8,3)`. Notice how you won't be creating `x` and `y` for `t1` because it uses the other appropriate constructor.

Comment: @ahmadhussain `x.n` will have the value `a`, `x.m` will have the value `b`, `y.n` will have the value `c` and `y.m` will have the value `d`.

Answer (score 3):

from the line `x = one(a, b);`
it jumps to line 
`one(int a, int b)`
and executes the parameterized constructor of `one`

same for line `y = one(c, d);`

Answer (score 2):

Current approach works only if you have a default constructor in one class.
It is better to initialize members in constructor initialization list:

```
two(int a, int b, int c, int d) 
    : x(a,b), y(c,d)
{
        cout << "made one two\n";
}
```